Ways to overload an already overloaded operator in a C++ standard library class?
I'm trying to implement my own matrix class (2d array), which uses a [] operator to access it's content and a std::unique_ptr<> to hold it - I'm aware there are easier/better ways to tackle this but I want to do it this way, if possible.
I can overload the [] operator for my class, but not for std::unique_ptr since it already does that.
matrix m(5,5, 1);     //create a 5x5 matrix filled with 1's
matrix[row];          //this uses my overloaded [] and returns a unique_ptr
matrix[row][column];  //this uses unique_ptr's overloaded [], can't do my own checks

Is there an elegant way to overload this operator or intercept column index via [] operator?
I thought about creating a wrapper class for std::unique_ptr<> that inherits from it but I prefer to use a pure class instead.

Short answer is no. C++ doesn't work this way. The fact that you need such an overload is an indication of bad design.

@Evg Could you elaborate on the bad design part?

I can't because you don't even show the interface of your matrix class in the question body. But it's a general rule: if you need some trick to implement what you want, it's a red flag of bad design. Exclusions exist but are rare.

Does std::mdspan do what you want?  (C++23)

Why are you returning an std::unique_ptr? If this std::unique_ptr gets destructed, it will attempt to delete the memory it points at which in this case is probably not the desired effect.

Most likely, you want matrix[row] to return your own class representing a row in the matrix; which in turn implements operator[] to access individual elements.

@ChukwujiobiCanon The class has a unique_ptr to an array of unique_ptr's as it's attribute, so as far as I'm concerned none of these are going to go out of scope before the object itself does. Edit: Forgot to mention, but [] overload function returns a reference to a chosen pointer.

@greenguy0120 Please show your code instead of trying to describe it.

@Eljay Pretty much! Although I wanted to do it by myself, hence I didn't use std::vector or other things.

Side note: C++23 adds multi-dimensional [] operator support, but before that the best advice is to write something like doug's answer here or james's answer here Do not return a unique_ptr because smart pointers imply ownership and the matrix is already the owner of its data.

If you want to do this the hard way, no vector, here is an excellent framework to start from

@user4581301 Is the data ownership issue going to cause bugs or is it bad practice/design but otherwise fine?

Data ownership means (among other things)  when the owner's gone, the owned data is gone. Unless you want your matrix to lose the row every time you return a pointer to a row, do not return an owning pointer. You could share ownership with shared_ptrs, but that makes things a lot more complicated than they need to be. In virtually every case, a matrix owns its data and everyone else merely borrows it, and you need to be solving a really interesting problem to require anything else.

Note that you also cannot safely return a smart pointer of any type to the middle of an array. You have to either own all of an object or none of it.

Review your design. It will be easier for us if you provide a [example].

You cannot do this directly, for very good reasons, but you can make a wrapper to make it look and feel like you can subscript the value returned. I'm using std::array<int,16> as a stand-in for your matrix class, here.
auto const ptr = std::make_unique<std::array<int,16>>();
At{ptr}[7] = 8;
assert(At{ptr}[7] == 8);

// the following should not compile:
At at{ptr};
at[7] = 12;

This is a possible, sketched, implementation:
template <typename T>
class At {
  private:
    T& value;
  public:
    At(std::unique_ptr<T> const& ptr) : value{*ptr} {}
    template <typename I>
    decltype(auto) operator[](I const i) const&& {
      return value[i];
    }
};

Note that At::operator[] only works on const rvalue references such that lvalues are strongly discouraged and users are not tempted to keep an At object lying around. This is not perfect, because you can find a way around that if you really want to.
